# AutoLoader for unknown project levels

Tags: php, autoloader

I would like to make my projects so fexible that one can simply copy+paste them into each other.

My project structure is ProjectName/(bin, config, lib).

After copy+paste I would have a chain like ProjectName1/lib/ProjectName2/lib/ProjectName3/.

Now it would be great if the Autoloader searches files acording to the level where the file is been called.

For example if a class within ProjectName1/lib/ProjectName2/lib/ calls "new Config" it should receive the config file located in ProjectName1/lib/ProjectName2/config/config.php.

(But not the one in ProjectName1/config/config.php and neither the on in ProjectName1/lib/ProjectName2/lib/ProjectName3/config/config.php).

Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
Does it make sense to make files unique? For example: If 'config.php' was 'ProjectName2Config.php' there is (almost) no chance for conflicts. So the autoloader could search everywhere and will eventually find it's file.

Edit: 
Each project would have his own autoloader availible for copy+paste reasons. However I thought that I would load just the one for ProjectName1. Is it better to load them all so that each one can stay simple?

Cheers,
Peter

PS: I just came back from a 3 years programming break. I am also happy, if you tell me that above is gennerally a bad idea and give me the reason why :-)

Comment: Just write a php-function that does just that and register it as autoloader -- just play with it. the downside might be that codeing tools will have a hard time finding the correct classes, and so might you if the structure gets sufficiently messy. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a strange way to manage your projects.
Where would be the main script of Project1 and the one of Project2 ?

For example, what I do is I write this in my index.php or main project/lib include file :

```
<?php define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/'); ?>
```

And I always use this ROOT_PATH as a start of inclusion paths.

In your case Project1 ROOT_PATH would be something like "/var/www/Project1/" and Project2 ROOT_PATH would be "/var/www/Project1/lib/Project2/"

Thus a new Config in Project1 and in Project2 would use their own config.php file.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds good, as long I don't move back. But say I have:

    Project1 starts...

    $project2 = new Project2;
    $someValue = $project2->getSomeThing();
    
    Project1 continues....

   new SomeThingFromProject1();

In this case ROOT_PATH would be taken from Project2, right?

Comment: To answer your question: I Intend to use Project2 like in Example from the other edit: If I am working on Project1 and could need something from Project2 I would prefer to include the entire project instead of copy just the part that I need. I hope this is easier to manage i.e. when Project2 is updated eventually. Maybe I should rather use the word "package" and not "project".

Comment: In the case of "package" or "module", I understand. I would then have a project with its library, modules / packages (and other stuff). And every module / package would have it's own configs, views, controllers, sqls or whatever and would be independent.